# Understanding Qt view-model architecture: when to create and how to cleanup indexes in QAbstractItemModel implementation?

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

I'm currently migrating my project from `QTreeWidget` to `QtreeView`, and have a lot of problems caused by poor understanding of the Qt model-view design. So far I couldn't find answers even in Qt examples.

I've implemented my `QAbstractItemModel`. I'm returning strings to be viewed in the `QTreeView` through `data` method. Now, the underlying data will change in runtime. To handle this my model is subscribed to a notification that does `emit dataChanged(index(0,0), index(rowCount() - 1, LastColumn));`. The question is: how to create and cleanup `QModelIndex` objects? One of the Qt examples reimplements `index` method, so I did the same:

```
QModelIndex CFileListModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &/*parent*/) const
{
    QModelIndex index = createIndex(row, column);
    return index;
}
```

However, data is static in that example and in my case it changes at runtime. Is my `index` implemetation correct? What if `index` is called more than once for the same coordinates? Do I need to somehow cleanup old indexes before emitting `dataChanged`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question about "deletion" of indices makes no sense in the light of the semantics of C++. There is simply no way for you to destroy an object that you returned by value from inside of a function - at least not without resorting to purposeful dirty hacks. So let's forget about it.

The `dataChanged` signal and the lifetime of indices are not really related. When your `index()` method returns an index, you are not the one who can "delete" it; whoever called your model's `index()` method is responsible for destructing the index. Never mind that the index you give out is not allocated in the free store anyway, so the notion of deletion doesn't apply at all.

The `QModelIndex` is what it says on the box: an index. When it comes to how it might be used, it's very much like a C++ iterator. It comes with a few caveats that mirror iterator caveats:

1. It must be created by the model using a factory method `index()`. Internally you use the `createIndex()` factory to create it for you within the model. Think of iterator-returning methods of C++ containers do (`begin()`, `end()`, etc.).
2. It must be used at once and then discarded. It won't remain valid if you make changes to the model. The same general limitation applies to C++ container iterators.
3. If you need to keep a model index over time use a `QPersistentModelIndex`. The C++ standard library doesn't offer this.

The lifetime of an index is out of your control. You create it, you give it out with an expectation that it will be used according to this protocol. The user (the view, for example) is supposed to use it subject to the limitations listed above. If a view, for example, holds on to an index for too long (through intervening modifications), it's entirely OK that it will result in undefined behavior (say, a crash).

When you emit (or receive, if you're a view or a proxy model) `dataChanged`, you shouldn't expect any indices given out prior to that point to remain usable. The persistent indices of course should still work, but it's ok to invalidate those if, say, the pointed-to index was removed (think of a cell being removed from a spreadsheet, **not** the cell's data being changed!).

**If you gave out an index, then emit `dataChanged`, and *any* of your model's methods get called with that old index, you're free to crash, assert, abort, whatever.**

Let's also be clear about how you use `dataChanged`: you're supposed to emit it whenever an item of data at a given index changes. You should be as specific as possible: it is *not* a good idea at all to simply tell your views that everything has changed if, in fact, it hasn't. If one index has changed, emit the signal with `topLeft` and `bottomRight` set to the same index. If a small rectangular area has changed, emit the corners of this rectangle. If multiple unrelated items have changed that are too far away to be meaningfully bundled in a small enclosing index rectangle, you should indicate such changes separately for each changed item.

You should definitely use [modeltest](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Model_Test) to verify that your model behaves sanely.

This can be done by adding the `modeltest.cpp` and `modeltest.h` to your project, and instantiating the tester for each model instance. You can do it directly within your model:

```
#include "modeltest.h"

MyModel(QObject * parent) : ... {
   new ModelTest(this, parent);
   ...
}
```

You also need to handle persistent indices for your model, and that's a separate issue. The documentation says:

> Models that provide interfaces to resizable data structures can provide implementations of insertRows(), removeRows(), insertColumns(),and removeColumns(). When implementing these functions, it is important to notify any connected views about changes to the model's dimensions both before and after they occur:
>
> - An insertRows() implementation must call beginInsertRows() before inserting new rows into the data structure, and endInsertRows() immediately afterwards.
> - An insertColumns() implementation must call beginInsertColumns() before inserting new columns into the data structure, and endInsertColumns() immediately afterwards.
> - A removeRows() implementation must call beginRemoveRows() before the rows are removed from the data structure, and endRemoveRows() immediately afterwards.
> - A removeColumns() implementation must call beginRemoveColumns() before the columns are removed from the data structure, and endRemoveColumns() immediately afterwards.
>
> The private signals that these functions emit give attached components the chance to take action before any data becomes unavailable. The encapsulation of the insert and remove operations with these begin and end functions also enables the model to manage persistent model indexes correctly. If you want selections to be handled properly, you must ensure that you call these functions. If you insert or remove an item with children, you do not need to call these functions for the child items. In other words, the parent item will take care of its child items.

Comment: Besides, you write the model, why do you ask someone else whether your model stores the indexes? If **you** don't store them, you don't store them.

Comment: I'm fine with C++ basics. The fact that a resource is returned by value doesn't mean I don't have to `release` it or whatever. Or call `reset` on the model when its old state becomes invalid. It's always better to doublecheck than to deal with memory leaks later, and the docs are not clear on the subject. Since I'm inheriting the base `QAbstractItemModel`, I have no idea (short of inspecting its source) whether it stores indexes or not.

Comment: How do you even use `modeltest`? My project refuses to compile as soon as I add `QT += testlib`

Comment: The `QModelIndex` class is very simple. When in doubt, you can always look at the sources. It's a four member read-only struct with a private constructor.

Comment: `The fact that a resource is returned by value doesn't mean I don't have to release it or whatever.` You're overthinking it and coming up with non-existent problems. `QModelIndex` comes with an idiomatic non-public factory within `QAbstractItemModel`. That's the only way to prevent model users from making their own, invalid, indices. It's a common pattern. Just because there is a factory doesn't mean there's management. The abstract model doesn't have a `reset` method, and a model reset has got nothing much to do with non-persistent indexes. A model reset is like a new disc is in the drive.