# QAbstractItemModel: how to correctly remove item and recalculate indexes?

Tags: qt, qabstractitemmodel

Never used this class before. I inherited my class from it. How to correctly remove item and recalculate indexes? What do I need send with dataChange (what arguments will be in this signal)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding Qt view-model architecture: when to create and how to cleanup indexes in QAbstractItemModel implementation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941445/understanding-qt-view-model-architecture-when-to-create-and-how-to-cleanup-inde) The other question has an answer that explains the semantics of the indices. The big takeaway: indices are ephemeral. The user of the indices must not use them after any change to the model.

Answer (score 2):

To remove row from model:

```
void MyModel::operationToRemoveItemAtRow(int row) {
    beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), row, row); // no parent, one row to remove

    someListWhichHoldsDataForModel.removeAt(row);

    endRemoveRows();
}
```

See [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#subclassing) or this [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstracttablemodel.html#subclassing).